# Prioridades de operadores c++

Tags: c++

Tengo que realizar un programa, el cual me calcule (con base al radio) la longuitud de la circuferencia, area del circulo, volumen de la esfera. El problema es que cuando se va a regresar los valores solamente la longuitud y el area son correctos. El volumen me da un valor que no corresponde al radio que le ingreso y es porque no sé como darle prioridad a las operaciones. ¿Me podrian explicar?.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
/*
 * 
 * Programa C++ que lee el radio y calcula:
 * - longitud de la circunferencia
 * - área del circulo
 * - volumen de la esfera
 * correspondiente al radio introducido
 */
float circunferencia (float radio){
   float resultado;
   const float pi=3.14; 
  
  resultado = (2 * radio * pi);
  cout<<"La circunferencia es: "<<resultado<<endl;

}

float area (float radio){
  float  resultado;
  const float pi=3.14;

  resultado = (pi * pow(radio,2));
  cout<<"El area es: "<<resultado<<endl;
}

float volumen (float radio){
 float resultado;
 float pi = 3.14;

 resultado = (4/3) * pi * pow(radio,3);
 cout<<"El volumen es: "<<resultado<<endl;
}


int main () {

float radio; 


cout<<"Ingrese el radio: "<<endl;
cin>>radio;

circunferencia(radio);
area(radio);
volumen(radio);



    return 0;
}
```

El valor que da cuando pongo el radio (10) es = 3140.
Pero el valor correcto que deberia dar es = 4186

Comment: Cada literal tiene su tipo. [Aquí](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions%23Literals) en la sección de literales puedes obtener más información al respecto.

Comment: Entiendo, me será de mucha utilidad. Gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La operación (4/3) da un resultado entero (un 1), y por eso multiplica por 1 y no por 1.33. Usa por ejemplo 4.0/3

Cambia el  `resultado = (4/3) * pi * pow(radio,3);`
Por:  `resultado = (4.0/3) * pi * pow(radio,3);`

Otro tema, la definición de PI te aconsejo que fuera global. Imagina que después le quieres añadir algún decimal, deberías buscar todas las definiciones del código.

Comment: Te lo agradezco muchisimo

Answer (score 2):

Suena a que esos métodos no deberían ser float porque no devuelven nada, y los números que uses deberían ser float y no enteros para que las operaciones no hagan suposiciones

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 * Programa C++ que lee el radio y calcula:
 * - longitud de la circunferencia
 * - área del circulo
 * - volumen de la esfera
 * correspondiente al radio introducido
 */
 
const float pi = 3.1416;
 
void circunferencia (float radio){
  float resultado;

  resultado = (2 * radio * pi);
  cout<<"La circunferencia es: "<<resultado<<endl;

}

void area (float radio){
  float resultado;
  
  resultado = pi * pow(radio, 2.0);
  cout<<"El area es: "<< resultado <<endl;
}

void volumen (float radio){
 float resultado;

 resultado = ((4.0/3.0) * pi) * pow(radio, 3.0);
 cout<<"El volumen es: "<< resultado <<endl;
}


int main () {

    float radio; 
    
    
    cout<<"Ingrese el radio: "<<endl;
    cin>>radio;
    
    circunferencia(radio);
    area(radio);
    volumen(radio);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, muchas gracias por tu aporte!!! :D

Comment: @AndresFelipeMorenoHurtado buena pregunta. Acá estamos siempre pa intentar ayudar :)